# proportions in css overlapping

Tags: html, css

i am having a problem on my site i am trying to make the bottom textbox and submit button i have are styled like so

```
#chat-box-div-submit{
position:fixed;
bottom:5;
right:5px;
margin:10px;
height:30px;
background:darkcyan;
width:70px;
outline: none;
}
#chat-box-div-txtinpt{
width:65%;
left:305px;
min-width:100px;
position:fixed;
bottom:5;
margin:10px;
outline-color: darkcyan;
}
.submit{
background:darkcyan;
border:0;
border-radius:4px;
}
.big-txtinpt{
height:30px;
background: transparent;
border-radius:4px;
border:2px solid darkcyan;
color:darkcyan;
}
```

and i had it to where it looked really nice on some computers (the submit button was directly beside the textbox no pixels in between) but it would overlap or be spread out on others could someone please help me [here is the site](http://billischill.ddns.net/billischill-2.0/index_eventualy.html) and here is a  [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7Lsprdus/)

Comment: Welcome. Jsfiddle please. Also see [mcve]

Comment: can you help me out

Comment: I need you to follow the instructions in my previous comment in order to help.

Comment: the fiddle changes it

Comment: Include everything in it. Html, css, JavaScript, and whatever else you used.

Comment: i have even the js

Comment: it is exactly the same

Comment: The js field appears to be empty

Comment: can you please just help the js is completely irrelevant anyways

Comment: Does the problem happen also without the js?

Comment: no the js doesnt effect it at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use flexbox for this:

```css
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }
body { 
  background: rgb(28, 28, 29);
  margin: 2em;
}
#chatbox {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  height: 2em;
}
#chatbox input {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: transparent;
  border: 2px solid darkcyan;
}
#chatbox input[type=text] {
  color: darkcyan;
  border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
}
#chatbox input[type=submit] {
  width: 70px;
  background: darkcyan;
  border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="chatbox">
  <input type="text" />
  <input type="submit" value="Send" />
</div>
```